# Unable to get page name in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am customizing a wordpress plugin which is used for popup email subscribing. when the user submits email he gets a confirmation email in which iam sending my custom html to him. I have five different pages on my web site and every page has that popup. what iam doing is that i want to get the name of my page than according to that i want to send html in email. I did exactly the same thing for other plugin and it worked but in this popup plugin iam unable to get the page name from where it is called.
I have tried following things but failed.

```
global $post;      /* this worked perfect on other plugin */
$pagename = $post->post_name;
if($pagename=="page1")
{
 // html page1 //
}
else
{
// html page2 //
}
```

Just tried this

```
$slug = basename(get_permalink()); 
if($slug=="page1") and so on
```

Comment: You can use echo "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

Comment: @developer didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, you need to get `title` for this, as

```
$post = get_post( $post );

$pagename = isset( $post->post_title ) ? $post->post_title : '';
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If you tried and it didn't work, why did you accept the answer @AmmarUlHassan?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use [get_queried_object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object). It retrieve the currently-queried object - page, post, taxonomy, whatever...

You can try this code, its working for me:

```
$qo = get_queried_object();
if ( 'page' !== $qo->post_type ) {
    //Here you can be sure, that you are in page query, so this is available
    $pagename = $qo->post_name;
}
```

Comment: this works on other pages but failing in my current plugin php file :(

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this:

```
$pagename = get_query_var('pagename');  
if ( !$pagename && $id > 0 ) {  
    // If a static page is set as the front page, $pagename will not be set. Retrieve it from the queried object  
    $post = $wp_query->get_queried_object();  
    $pagename = $post->post_name;  
}
```

Comment: I did this but failed these things work on other pages but not in this popup plugin files :(

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Why are you commenting on only my answers. Many of them are not explaining it.

Comment: Because you're not explaining what you have done, you're only saying "try this". While the code might be obvious to you, it will not be to a newbie seeing your answer. There are a couple of benefits: a.) Your answers are seen in a better light and 2.) you might earn some IIP's (Imaginary Internet Points) that signify to others that your answers are more likely to be right. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thanks. I will follow this